# Migrate to DNN Evoq 8.2

Tags: migration, dotnetnuke

Our team is developing a site in DNN Community for a client that runs EVOQ 8.2. The site is not very complex, 3 pages with 3 modules, unfortunately, our client won't give us access to their EVOQ instance and is requesting exporting the site for implementing it themselves. How can we export a community DNN site compatible with EVOQ 8.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the site import/export functionality to export all of the pages and their content. This is not something "available" in DNN 9, but if they're still on 8 you should be good.

Here are the basic steps.

1. Login as Host/SuperUser
2. Navigate to the Host Menu > Site
   Management
3. Choose the Export Site template option
4. Choose the site you're exporting, give it a name/description.
5. Under advanced, choose Include Content and Include Files. You can probably     uncheck a lot of the other options, but up to you on what you want to include.
6. Export the template. That will create two files in /portals/_default
7. Copy those two files to the customer's /portals/_default folder
8. Either create a new site, based on the template, or choose the Admin/Site Wizard option and apply that template to an existing DNN portal.

I would highly recommend TESTING that process out before running it in their production environment. Most things should work on the Evoq site, but you never know.

Also be sure that they have all the same extensions (modules/skins/themes) installed on both sites.

The other option is simply create new pages in Evoq and just copy/paste the content.